# Angular material select box not showing properly

Tags: angular, angular-material, material-design, angular8

I an Angular 8 project with Angular Material, I have a form and in it I need to add a select box that have this style:

[image: design]

Note the label "Select an option" style how stands in the middle of the line.

The html code:

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-label> Select an option</mat-label>
  <mat-select>
    <mat-option *ngFor="let type of types" [value]="type">{{type}}</mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

The ts code:

```
types: string[] = [
    'Charmander', 'Bulbasaur', 'Squirtle'
  ];
```

I can't find anywhere in the documentation how to make the "Select an option" to stay in the middle of the line.
Here is the [stackblitz link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9z2mx5?file=src/app/select-reset-example.html)

Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 2):

set appearance to outline like below:

```html
<mat-form-field appearance="outline">
    <mat-label> Select an option</mat-label>
    <mat-select>
        <mat-option *ngFor="let type of types" [value]="type">{{type}}</mat-option>
    </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```